# Flutter Positioned widget results in an error: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter

The following code results in an error: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The cause for this error is the **Positioned** widget, but I'm not sure why...

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Positioned(
          left: 32.0,
          child: Container(
            width: 128.0,
            height: 128.0,
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: `Positioned` needs to be a child of `Stack`.

Comment: you can get the same effect by removing `Positioned` widget and give a margin of `EdgeInsets.only(left:32)` to the `Container`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Positioned` has to be in a `Stack` according to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) that says

> A widget that controls where a child of a Stack is positioned.
>
> A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack, and the path from
>   the Positioned widget to its enclosing Stack must contain only
>   StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like
>   RenderObjectWidgets).

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 32.0,
              child: Container(
                width: 128.0,
                height: 128.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: My bad, missed the Stack issue in the documentation (I was barking up the wrong tree). Thanks for the pointer :)